# Rearranging array of vertices into array of edges

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3x2 array where each row represents a vertex of a triangle. I would like to reshape it in order to obtain a new array where each row represents a side.

I'm currently trying the following approach:

```
points = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0]])

sides = np.array([
    [points[0], points[1]],
    [points[1], points[2]],
    [points[2], points[0]]
])
```

Is there any build in function to do that in a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

Elegance is a matter of definition, if you find the following solution more elegant, is up to you. I use [np.roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) to shift the indices from `[0], [1], [2]` to `[1] [2] [0]` and then pair the shifted and unshifted arrays using [np.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), similar to what you do in your manual code (watch the index pairs you create, they are the same).

```
import numpy as np

points = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0]])
print(points)
#array([[0, 0],
#       [0, 1],
#       [1, 0]])

sides = np.stack([ 
    points, 
    np.roll(points, -1, axis=-1)
], axis=-1)

print(sides)
#array([[[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]],
#
#       [[0, 1],
#        [1, 0]],
#
#       [[1, 0],
#        [0, 0]]])
```

Keep in mind that this solution does not work for an arbitrary amount of vertices, but just three.